# {Nativescript} Add more properties in model

Tags: nativescript

I am a newbie in nativescript. Currently I am creating app with 2 properties in my customer-view-model.js as shown below, and it's running well.

```
function Customer( nama ) {
  this.nama = nama;      
  this.complete = false;
}    
module.exports = Customer;
```

When I am add more properties like code below then my app thrown an error with message `ReferenceError: telpon is not defined`

```
function Customer( nama ) {
  this.nama = nama;      
  this.telpon = telpon;
  this.complete = false;
}    
module.exports = Customer;
```

I have no idea what i'm missing. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got "nama" from parameter at first line, that's why first was good but not telpon, so if its input parameter you need to add it first line (as definition) or use something from 3 lines inside function to set variable to some default value

this.something are properties of model,
this.telpon was done okey but you were assigning variable to property which was undefined

```
function Customer( nama,telpon ) {
  this.nama = nama;      
  this.telpon = telpon;
      //this.telpon = 1; 
      //this.telpon = "string"; 
      //this.telpon = false/true; 
  this.complete = false;
}    
module.exports = Customer;
```

Comment: Many thanks @Marek, when I am use this.telpon = telpon; still get error but when use this.telpon = 1; everything is normal. please help again